# When can you call yourself PHP professional?

Tags: php, oop, frameworks, smarty

What makes you professional PHP programmer? When you know OOP, smarty, framework. I guess that's it, right? If not, then what else?

Comment: when you make money writing PHP perhaps...

Comment: Knowing Smarty doesn't necessarily make you a PHP "professional", but might make you a Smarty "professional". I guess it would depend on whether or not you could still function with PHP and not using Smarty (or any other framework - could you write your own?).

Comment: i dont think he ment it that way, i think he ment to say when does someone call himself a skilled PHP programmer? - i dont know the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional).

If you make money at it, you're a professional. If you are "trained" for it (BS CS anyone?) you're a professional.

Answer (score 2):

When someone pays you to write PHP code.